# How to automatically add handler to the global map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have Application singleton wich has method

```
void addHandler(const std::string& command, std::function<std::string (const std::string&)> handler)
```

I want to create a lot of cpp files with handlers like this

```
//create_user_handler.cpp
Application::getInstance()->addHandler("create_user", [](std::string name) {
   UserPtr user = User::create(name);
   return user->toJson();
});
```

How automatically call this from my cpp files?

I try to change from `void addHandler` to `bool addHandler` and than use

```
namespace {
  bool b = Application::getInatance()->addHandler......
}
```

but it didn't work for me

**Udate**
It works now, but could it be done in a better way, without unused bool variable?

Comment: Why didn't the last code work for you?

Comment: Actually it works now. I compiled all my handlers as a static lib and then linked it with main.cpp. When I just compiled handlers with main.cpp it got worked. But is there better way to do it? Without unused variable.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of static class instantiation.

Pseudo code - 
Add a registrator class.

```
class Registrator {
   template <typename Func>
   Registrator(const std::string& name, Func handler) {
     Application::getInstance()->addHandler(name, handler);
   }
};
```

And in each cpp file, create a static class object:

```
test.cpp

static Registrator test_cpp_reg("create_user", [](std::string name) {
   UserPtr user = User::create(name);
   return user->toJson();
});
```

Comment: Thank's I guess it's the best way to do it

Comment: In addition, anonymous namespaces could be used instead of static `namespace { Registrator test_cpp_reg(........); }`

Comment: @SergeyKolesov I totally ship anonymous namespace :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that addHandler() should return bool?  Otherwise, you can't assign to the bool variable.

To remove the bool return of addHandler, make the call from the constructor of some other class that you in turn instantiate statically.

This kind of code can work, but it is tricky.  The problem is that in C/C++, the order of static-storage initializers is undefined.  So while a static initializer is allowed to call any code, if that code references as-yet-uninitialized data, it will fail.  And unfortunately the failure is non-deterministic.  It might work for a while, and then you change some compiler flag or module order, and splat!

One trick is to implement the instance state of getInstance() using a dumb pointer, because that is always initialized to zero (null) before any of the static initializers fire.  For example, the following code will print "Added foo" before main starts:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Application {
public:
    static Application* getInstance() {
        // Not thread-safe!
        if (instance == 0) {
            instance = new Application;
        }
        return instance;
    }
    typedef std::function<std::string(const std::string&)> HANDLER;
    typedef std::map<std::string, HANDLER> HANDLER_MAP;
    bool addHandler(const std::string& command, HANDLER handler) {
        handlerMap.insert(HANDLER_MAP::value_type(command, handler));
        std::cout << "Added " << command << "\n";
        return true;
    }
    HANDLER_MAP handlerMap;
    static Application* instance;
};
Application* Application::instance;

std::string myHandler(const std::string&) { return "";  }
bool b = Application::getInstance()->addHandler("foo", myHandler);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the question I access to Application using getInstance(), `return bool` it is just a trick to call `addHandler` using static initialization and I just want to find a better way to do it without such hacks

Comment: Yes, you'll note in my response: 
" assume that addHandler() should return bool? Otherwise, you can't assign to the bool variable.

To remove the bool return of addHandler, make the call from the constructor of some other class that you in turn instantiate statically."

Comment: I do however still caution you about static initializers.  Would you care to share your implementation of getInstance()?  Or is it supplied by a framework?

Comment: Code for getInstance 
`Application& Application::getInstance()
{
 static Application* app = nullptr;
 if(app == nullptr)
  app = new Application;

 return *app;
};`

Comment: Yes, I use async networking and all my hanlers run in the same thread

Comment: PS: if you are using C++ 11, you can use a function-local static to implement your singleton very simply and also thread-safe:
X* X::getInstance() {
   static X* instance = new X(...);
return instance; 
}

Comment: And (also in C++ 11) if you want your singleton to destruct on exit: X* X::getInstance() { static X instance(...); return &instance; }   Both of these cork pre-C++11 but just aren't thread-safe